# How to create JapserServer report templates?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm pretty new to JasperReports, Jaspersoft Studio, and JasperServer but I've got a JasperServer instance up and running and have been using it to create reports from Ad Hoc views. This works well but I'd like to make some report templates so that reports run from JasperServer can have branded headers/footers etc.

I worked through [this tutorial](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/creating-custom-template-jaspersoft-studio) and was able to create what I thought was a fine template but when I try export it as a JasperServer template I get all sorts of validation warnings and indeed trying to run reports using it from the server results in errors.

Here's an example of the warnings I'm seeing:

`The style ChartValueAxisTickFormat was not found in the template`

And the errors I get on the server when trying to use these templates look like those described [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-errors-when-compiling-report-expressions-class-file). I have tried using templates without any text fields or variables though. In fact, the unexpected tokens it complains about are usually actual field ids... do I need to anticipate the fields that would be used when creating a template? Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of having templates for reports created from ad hoc views?

Anyway, there's quite a lot of information out there around creating templates for Jaspersoft Studio (iReport) reports but not a whole lot on templates for JasperServer reports.

It seems like there's something fundamental about templates for JasperServer reports that I'm missing. I'd appreciate any help with either the issues I am describing or being pointed toward better documentation for creating these templates specifically.

Edit:

I'm using Jasper Studio Profession 5.5.0.final on the desktop and a Jaspersoft BI Professional for AWS 5.5 instance as the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Report Template as in tutorial you have linked are for Jaspersoft Studio / static reports only. Adhoc templates are different types of objects which are described [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v550/configuring-ad-hoc#Templates_and_Generators)

Comment: Thanks for the link - so is the suggested pathway for authoring new templates to edit that default template jrxml file (`/public/templates/actual_size.510.jrxml`)? It's still now clear to me how a designer might create a new template in Studio that will work for Ad Hoc reports.

Comment: I think you can add custom templates, once they are deployed to folder they should be accessible. I have no practical experience with this specific functionality. Given standard JR behavior everything should work as long as resources are accessible within classpath, so if you deploy images and and external style references as separate objects to repository and reference them via repository URI you should be able to use your static templates for adhoc (untested)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same errors, and I have solved it by simply adding a styles to my report, in other words:

- In the outline of your report, Right click on Style -> create Style, then just change the name of the style by each name of missing styles apperead (for example, ChartValueAxisTickFormat).

[image: Styles]

- After creation of 55 styles in your report template in jasper Soft Studio, save the report, then export it as report template.

I hope this will help you.